# Как преобразовать double? в double на C#

Tags: c#, преобразование, типы

Есть поле класса типа `double?`, то есть оно может и не содержать значения.

А я в своем классе использую просто `double`.

Как сделать преобразование?

И как быть с `DateTime?` -> `DateTime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы уверены, что значение там *есть*, вы можете получить его так:

```
double? nd = ...;
double v = nd.Value;
```

Если не уверены, вам придётся сначала проверить:

```
double? nd = ...;
if (nd == null)
{
    // значения нет, обрабатываем этот случай
}
else
{
    // значение есть
    double d = nd.Value;
    // работаем с ним
}
```

Для случая, когда для отсутствующего значения подойдёт, например, 0.0, можно написать просто так:

```
double d = nd ?? 0.0;
```

Но как именно **правильно** реагировать на отсутствующее значение, решать только вам.

Comment: не уверен, что оно есть. Вполне возможно, что и не окажется.

Comment: @МаксимКутовой: Дописал ответ.

Comment: А как быть с DataTime?

Comment: @МаксимКутовой: точно так же не пробовали?

Comment: Попробовал... Все ОК

Answer (score 5):

Ну можно что-нибудь вот такое например:

```
double val = nullableDouble.HasValue ? nullableDouble.Value : 0.0;
```

Comment: если нету значения, то задавать для моего нули... Правильно?

Comment: да. Ну либо любое другое подходящее значение